Как с помощью кода Javascript на одной странице получить html код второй, которая находиться на том же домене?
Я создаю свой сайт используя конструктор Google Sites и у меня появилась необходимость подсчетов на одной странице используя данные с другой страницы.
Я хочу написать блок кода  на JavaScript`е который будет находиться на одной странице сайта(например: sites.google.com/view/*адрес*/result) который должен получить данные (html код) с второй страницы сайта(например: sites.google.com/view/*адрес*/data). В общем, чтобы страница /result зависела от данных на странице /data.
Перепробовал уже буквально все методы с интернета и целый день спрашивал у нейросети разные варианты но ничего не подошло, либо ошибка, либо код вообще не работает. Может быть здесь кто то работал с гугл сайтами и знает как это можн сделать?
P.S. Если я сюда пишу это значит что мне не помогли другие статьи с StackOverFlow
P.S.2 джаваскрипт я не знаю и с ним никогда не работал

Для начала, вы должны понять... HTML это статика и зависела от данных на странице - это ошибка, будет всегда одинаково. Если HTML на второй странице наполняется силами JS, то вам надо подключить вторую страницу через iframe. После этого наладить коммуникацию между страницами. Хотя все это представляется велосипедом и возможно это можно решить другими способами

@SwaD может вы посоветуете тогда какой-нибудь иной способ в котором мне будет легко разобраться? Либо подробнее раскроете вопрос про "велосипед"?

Рассказать как раз должны вы, что вы хотите сделать, зачем, почему. Еще раз HTML - это просто разметка текста, она статична и не меняется сама.

@SwaD я хочу чтобы при обновлении страницы на которой запущен скрипт я мог работать с актуальными данными на второй странице чтобы делать актуальные расчеты(например, на второй странице лежат наименования товаров и мне нужно получить их количество чтобы вывести на первой странице со статистикой), но пока не знаю как это можно реализовать

Ну либо ifraim юзать, либо, более правильно, смотреть код второй страницы. Там же наверняка данные получаются из какой то базенки. Этот код перетащить на первую страницу, данные получать, но не отрисовывать их, а просто с ними работать. Как это делать на гугл-сайте я не знаю.
